# Using ExternalProject_Add with catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to add an external project to catkin using the ExternalProject_Add feature in CMake. My CMakeLists.txt files looks something like follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add( foreignproject
  PREFIX foreignprojectlib
  GIT_REPOSITORY foreignproject.git
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE
  BUILD_COMMAND cmake --build .
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

project(rosproject)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include ${DIRECTORY_TO_FOREIGN_PROJECT_HEADERS}
  LIBRARIES rosproject foreignproject
  CATKIN_DEPENDS opencv2 roscpp tf
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(rosnode src/rosnode.cpp)
```

The problem I am coming across is that the header file from the external project is not being found. In fact, I'm finding that catkin_make (-j1) tries to build rosnode before it builds the external library. Could someone explain the proper way of using ExternalProject_Add or post an example of a CMakeLists.txt file that successfully uses ExternalProject_Add?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63259/using-externalproject_add-with-catkin/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2013-07-18**:
Hi there! I've found myself in a similar situation. Have you found a solution/workaround yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe catkin_package sets the include directories for downstream projects, but does not set the include directories for the current project.

You probably also need to do:

```
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${DIRECTORY_TO_FOREIGN_PROJECT_HEADERS}
)
```

Also, what @William said.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to add a dependency on the external project target, so that the node is built later:

```
add_dependencies(rosnode foreignproject)
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1